# How can I load a Vector into a single column of an Array in Julia

Tags: julia, radix

That's it. My program generates a vector of Int64s, and each time I need to stack each Vector into a M by N Matrix

Everything. e.g.
Push, Append, hcat [], (), {}, even ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You don't give enough information. Is the matrix already allocated to its final size (apparently, you know already it will be a specific size), or are going to grow it iteratively (which will be inefficient)?

Comment: Thank you for all being so fast! Yes, as mentioned I need to iterate the placement of the vector in the array. When I do this, I get errors. I got as far as testing my code with examples just as you show. Then came all sorts of errors. Many different kinds. Most read like something out of GTP3. I wondered how a language could let you do something in principal, then rain down errors when you attempt to generalise. I though math was different to that.

Comment: I'm not quite able to undestand what you mean, unfortunately. What are you trying to generalize, and how? Can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new matrix use hcat:

```
julia> hcat([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6
```

This will also work with vector of vectors:

```
julia> vecs = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

julia> a = hcat(vecs...)
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9
```

If performance is an issue `reduce` combined with `hcat` will be more verbose but much faster:

```
reduce(hcat, vecs)
```

To put data into a column use broadcasted assignment:

```
julia> a[:,2] .= [40,50,60];

julia> a
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  40  7
 2  50  8
 3  60  9
```

Comment: Ooops. It was the broadcast I forgot to use. Apologies.

Comment: Broadcasting is not actually needed, it works just as well without: `a[:, 2] = [40,50,60];`

Comment: When an entire column is updated and matrix is large enough broadcasting `.=` is faster than `=`. When updating a  1000x1000 matrix I can see 2x speedup